# How can I expand a active window?

Tags: interface

How can I expand an active window? Like in maya how you click space bar to focus in on just one window. Thansk for you help

Comment: Hover your cursor over the window you want to expand and press *Shift+Spacebar*.

Comment: Or, CTRL+UParrow to maximize, CTRL+DOWNarrow to restore it. This works like SHIFT+Spacebar, and leaves window headers and menus visible. Alternatively, you can also use ALT+F10 to have just the full window area, without headers and menus...

Answer (score 2):

In blender 2.8, the new hotkey to maximize an active window is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to hide the top bar and some other UI elements as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To expand the window hover your cursor over it and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. Press it again to get back.
You may also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to do it.
[image]

To expand the window even more press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
[image]